# AWS MSK Error: error deleting MSK Configuration (arn:aws:kafka:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX): BadRequestException: Configuration is in use by one or more clusters

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-msk

I'm getting the below error when running `terraform apply` on my AWS infrastructure.

```
Error: error deleting MSK Configuration (arn:aws:kafka:us-east-2:XXXXXX:XXXXXX): BadRequestException: Configuration is in use by one or more clusters. Dissociate the configuration from the clusters.
{
  RespMetadata: {
    StatusCode: 400,
    RequestID: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  },
  InvalidParameter: "arn",
  Message_: "Configuration is in use by one or more clusters. Dissociate the configuration from the clusters."
}
```

My MSK configuration is as follows.

```
resource "aws_msk_configuration" "mskconfig" {
  kafka_versions = var.configuration_kafka_versions
  name           = "mskconfig"

  server_properties = <<PROPERTIES
...
PROPERTIES
}
```

The version variable is as follows.

```
variable "configuration_kafka_versions" {
  type = list(string)
  default = ["2.2.1", "2.8.1", "3.4.0"]
  description = "List of Apache Kafka versions which can use this configuration."
}
```

I tried to dissociate this config from the cluster - but I couldn't find a way to do so. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

By default, terraform will destroy a resource before creating a new one.

In this case, as the error states, the MSK configuration is always in use by the cluster and cannot be deleted without dissociating. But your MSK cluster must always hold a config associated with it.

To resolve this, change the lifecycle behaviour as follows, and it will make Terraform create a new configuration and associate it with the cluster before deleting the old one.

```
lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
```

However, when creating a new config without deleting the old one, the new one's name will conflict with the old one. A quick workaround to fix that would be to make the config name change each time you add a new version.

```
resource "aws_msk_configuration" "mskconfig" {
  kafka_versions = var.configuration_kafka_versions
  name           = "mskconfig-${replace(element(var.configuration_kafka_versions, length(var.configuration_kafka_versions)-1), "/[.]/", "-")}"

  server_properties = <<PROPERTIES
...
PROPERTIES

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

This will create a new config (e.g. `"mskconfig-3-4-0"`) first and after upgrading the cluster, the old config will be deleted.